# Problema con EF6 en producción

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

Tengo un proyecto `EF6` con los respectivos `CRUD` a una Base de Datos `Oracle`, en desarrollo me funciona normal, pero cuando paso a producción me retorna el error:

> The underlying provider failed on Open. -    at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func  `1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
>      at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass45`1.<ExecuteFunction>b__43()

¿Alguien sabe a qué se debe este error?

Comment: entiendo que falla el EntityConnection Open() por lo que deberias validar el connection string ya que no esta pudiendo conectar a la db Oracle en produccion

Comment: Para corroborar, desde mi ambiente de desarrollo me conecte a la BD de producción y funciona, así que el web.conmfig pasa a producción con las misma cadena de producción que debería funcionar pero me sale ese error. Saludos

Comment: Aparte de eso, en el proyecto tengo la dll del EF6 (pienso que con eso es suficiente), se me viene a la mente si tal vez es necesario instalar algo extra de oracle en el Servidor???

Comment: seguramente debas instalar el ODAC, para tener el provider que permite el acceso a Oracle

Answer (score 0):

En tu servidor debes tener instaladas las librerías *Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC)*, preferiblemente la versión que incluye los *Oracle Developer Tools*, los puedes descargar desde el siguiente enlace:

[Oracle Data Access Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index-101290.html)